# Tracking changes of complex types in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I get entities that have complex types changed in the DBContext.ChangeTracker?  It works fine with primitives...

Models...

```
public class SalesPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesPerson SalesPerson { get; set; }
}
```

Repository method...

```
public void SaveChanges()
    {
         var changedItems = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
                .ToList();

        foreach (var item in changedItems)
        {
                if (item.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So... If I change the Client's name, the ChangeTracker (changedItems) shows a change... As expected.

If I assign a SalesPerson to the Client, the ChangeTracker doesn't pick it up.  (Because EF doesn't track changes of complex types).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The entity framework certainly handles 'complex types'. This would generally map to a daughter table of `SalesPerson` which would then be tracked as separate entities with a relationship back to `Client`. But FYI, the EF will save all your changes for you. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I am trying to get the item(s) from the ChangeTracker.Entries that have an EntityState of "EntityState.Added" or "EntityState.Modified".  It is fairly well documented that EF does not support ChangeTracking for complext types

Comment: Where is that documented? Is `SalesPerson` not part of the EF context? Why would it track `Client` but not `SalesPerson`.

Comment: Of course SalesPerson is part of the context... I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that it isn't.  And here are two links that I currently have open that indicate that complex types are not tracked.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456848(v=vs.100).aspx  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026452/entity-framework-code-first-update-a-single-property-of-a-complex-type  (I've read many others in researching this)

Comment: You don't seem to have a complex type. You have two related entities - and this is a completely different beast. Complex type do not have IDs and their properties are in the table of the enclosing type - in other words complex type is a way of grouping properties.

Comment: @Pawel:  Yes you are correct.  Nonetheless... How can I get the Client in the ChangeTracker when I add a SalesPerson?

Comment: Because your relation is only one way EF can't figure out that there is a Client for a SalesPerson. It also depends if the Client is a new or an existing entity. You can either fix the relation so that you can navigate from the Client to the SalesPerson and vice versa or you can the entity manually and EF should fix up the relationship. If the Client is an existing entity  you need to attach it or fetch from the database to prevent from creating duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pawel pointed me in the right direction...

I changed the SalesPerson class to include a List and added a SalesPersonId property to the Client class (See below).  I then added some DbModelBuilder (EF's fluent API) logic to wire everything up.

**Models**

```
public class SalesPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesPerson SalesPerson { get; set; }
    public int? SalesPersonId { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext class**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.SalesPerson)
            .WithMany(e => e.Clients)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.SalesPersonId);
    }
```

The repository stays the same.  Now It will detect changes because the SalesPersonId (a primitive) will change.

Thanks @Pawel